# XMLHTTP or ServerXMLHTTP working without http?

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest

I want to open a webpage and after that split the tags, without starting the url with 'www' not 'http'

[see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW21x.jpg)

```
<%
  dim objXMLHTTP

          ' holds a warning when the page seems to be invalid


  URL = Request.form("URL")
  if ( URL = "" ) then
    **'URL = "www.elmundo.es"**
  URL =  Request.QueryString("url")

  end if 

  Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", URL, false
  objXMLHTTP.Send

%>
```

Comment: I need your helpful to say if it is possible or not starting the url by 'www' instead 'http'.

Comment: If you don't specify the protocol, XMLHttpRequest won't know what protocol to use. So, what's the point?

Comment: Wow... I have a webpage where the user places the url and other script splits out the html tags, but the users normally places the urls starting by "www" not by "http" and in this way the scripts does not works...

Comment: And someone knows to tell me if I get place the url without protocol and after that when I click ENTER an scripts verify and add the correct protocol?